# Explain the statistics of Energy Usage Instrument in iOS

Tags: ios, instruments, energy

I am trying to find **Energy Usage** for my iOS App using **Instrument**.

I got the statistics like Time, Total Activity, Foreground App Activity, Audio Processing and 
Graphics in Percentage format. The sum of Foreground App Activity, Audio Processing and 
Graphics is different from Total Activity !

But I am not understanding what are **the meaning of these columns**? Can anybody please explain me **the meaning of these statistics** and how to use this?

Answer (score 1):

Latest [Energy Diagnostics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/MonitorEnergyWithInstruments.html) documentation says:

> The Energy Usage instrument shows a level from 0 to 20, indicating how
>   much energy your app is using at a given time. These numbers are
>   subjective. If your app’s energy usage level is occasionally high, it
>   doesn’t necessarily mean that your app has a problem. Your app may
>   simply require more energy for some of the tasks it performs. For
>   example, it may use GPS while performing complex network operations.
>   This is valid energy use. What you should look for are spikes or areas
>   of high energy use that are unexpected or that could be performed at
>   more optimal times.

Answer (score 0):

yes, sure there is difference. The best way to use it; do one at a time. observe each Activity Consumption and target optimizing that.

Comment: Thanks Prashant for your reply